# Run something in one application from another

Tags: android

(The title is a bit weird because the words "code" and "app" are [apparently forbidden](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373415/what-triggers-my-title-rejection/373418#373418) in question titles.)

I have two Android apps, one is a normal unprivileged app and one is a system app with the permission to shut down the system. From my normal app I want to initiate the shutdown. I know the package name and I have full control over both apps. Both are signed with the same key.

What is the most concise way to run code in one app from another?

One way would be a `Service` that I can then start with `intent.setComponent(...); startService(intent)`, but being a `Service` implies some background activity is going on, which isn't in my case.

Another way would be a `BroadcastReceiver` but that doesn't allow me to target a specific component, it requires an identifier whose purpose is conceptually to be received by other apps as well.

Is there another way with better fitting semantics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but being a Service implies some background activity is going on, which isn't in my case.

`Service` using AIDL is simply an inter-process communication (IPC) mechanism. What the recipient of that communication does in response to that communication is up to it.

Besides, you have some background activity going on. You wrote:

> From my normal app I want to initiate the shutdown

Shutting down a device *is* "background activity", at least in my interpretation of the expression.

> Another way would be a BroadcastReceiver but that doesn't allow me to target a specific component

Sure it does. You can use `setComponent()` on a broadcast `Intent` the same way that you do for binding to a `Service`, or starting a `Service`, or starting an `Activity`.

There are downsides of using `setComponent()`, notably a dependency between the two code bases. Basically, the `ComponentName` becomes part of the API contract, and since that maps to a Java class name, you are limited in your ability to refactor that class (new name, new package). However, there's nothing stopping you from using `setComponent()`.

For example, I describe using `setComponent()` for a broadcast in [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/04/11/android-o-implicit-broadcast-ban.html). In that case, I am deriving the `ComponentName` values via `PackageManager`, but that's just in service of this specific example.

> Is there another way with better fitting semantics?

For a single interaction, "fire and forget" sort of thing, where you are not looking for any sort of acknowledgment, I'd send an explicit broadcast (i.e., a broadcast of an `Intent` that uses the `ComponentName` to identify the recipient). And I'd definitely use a `signature`-level permission to secure it.

Comment: I expected a VTC for being "opinion based" but instead I got an excellent answer - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While CommonsWare's answer is excellent and the explicit broadcast with a custom permission is usually the way to go, in this particular case I ran into an issue.

Apps cannot receive broadcasts until they have started an activity because until then they remain in "stopped" state. So an app with only a `BroadcastReceiver` won't work.

And since I need to have an activity anyway, I put the shutdown code in the activity.

Comment: FWIW, there may be a way for a system app to avoid that restriction. Somewhere, there is a roster of which apps are/are not in the stopped state; you would need to arrange to get your system app updated to not be in the stopped state.